# Returning each text element just once from a selected range of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a google sheet file to track some of my expenses. I need to return an array starting from a column, that takes each text element from another column just once. For example, i want to take each element from column A  and return an array starting from C1 that takes all elements from A just once. What's the formula for doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A)
```

Comment: Quick and easy, so easy that i'm kind of embarassed, thank you a lot!